# How did the Boethusians linked the morrow after the Shabat with the Shabat Chol HaMoed Pesach?

Tags: history, talmud-bavli, sefirat-ha-omer, non-rabbinic-judaism, maseches-menachos

In Menachot 65a-66a (according to the Sefaria translation): The Boethusians say, Shavuot falls on a Sunday [because they hold that "the day after the Shabbat" refers to the Sunday after Shabbat Chol HaMoed Pesach].

What I would like to know specifically is why this group linked the 'day after the Shabat' with the Shabat Chol HaMoed Pesach. Upon which arguments did they build this view?

I know how their view was refuted, but I can't find any background on how they came to the conclusion - that by their view that the usage of the word Shabat refers to the seventh day  - the word Shabat had to mean the Shabat Chol HaMoed Pesach.

Anyone who could help me with that?

Comment: What else would it mean?

Comment: Perhaps they decided that they did not want to follow the mesorah so they had to pretend that Shabbat was literal.

Comment: @DoubleAA if you follow the vision one has to count from the second day of Pesach it's logically connected with Pesach. But if one assumes one has to count from the day after the seventh day Shabat, I don't see any link with the Pesach. Only if you take the moment the omer had to be brought, and take Yehoshua 5:11 into consideration a link with Pesach could be made, but these same verses talk about the second day of Pesach. And I don't see the Boethusians refer to it, so I don't know they made the link to Shabat Chol HaMoed Pesach from there.

Comment: @sabbahillel I understand, but why did it had to be connected with the Pesach according to their opinion? Which scriptures did they use to show it had to be the Shabbat Chol HaMoed Pesach and not just any Shabat after the Omer was brought before HaShem?... From the view that the second day of Pesach is ment here it is al clear, but if we leave this whole idea out of the picture for one moment and try to look at the verses from another perspective (just as the quoted source does) and take it to mean one has to count from 'sunday' then how does one know which sunday is ment?

Comment: I think I found a reason: I think that they took verses 4 and 5 about the date and time for Pesach and 6-8 about Chag HaMatzot with it's span of dates. These don't occur at specific days, but Shabat (the seventh day as mentioned in verse 3) could be taken as a weekly moed and therefore has a specific day assigned to it. Because Chag HaMatzot (de Pesach week) is annual moed it may start on different days every year, which is why no specific days are assigned to these dates. The day of the week it begins is not important, but the dates are....

Comment: The focus is on the seven-days of Chag Hatzot and so they took Shabat to refer as a reference to one of these days. Could this be their reason?

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily Shabbat Hol Hamo'ed Pesach. If they did a literal translation of the verse, it would mean "The morrow of the Shabbat of the day that the Omer was brought." So, the Omer was brought on the 16th of Sivan. If the 16th of Nissan was on Shabbat (the 2nd day of Pesach), then the 1st Shabbat would occur after Pesach was over.

Comment: @DanF oke, so how did they determined that the omer was brought on the 16th then? Because this would be the date others would start counting right?

Comment: My error. I forgot the exact wording as cited in the answer, below. It even says that the Omer was brought on the morrow of the Shabbat.

Comment: @DanF would the Boethusians also agree that the omer was waved on the day after the first day of Pesach?

Comment: @DanF I read the previous verses of Menachot but the Boethusians disagreed  who maintained that the reaping of the omer was not to take place at the conclusion of the (first day of the) festival. But it doesn't say why or what they thought to be the correct time to do so (to reap, give it to the kohanim to present it as a wave offering).

Comment: @DanF one more thing why exactly would it be a problem if the 1st Shabat would occur after the Pesach was over?

Answer (score 1):

They read the Parshiot as they are written. See ויקרא פרק-כג where the Torah says to keep Pesach and then **on the morrow of the Sabbath** to start counting the 7 weeks of the Omer after bringing the Omer **on the morrow of the Sabbath**.

Since they didn't care for Rabbinical explanations - *that the Sabbath in question in the first day of Pesach* - so the next available Sabbath is Shabbat-Chol-HaMo'ed.

> ד} אֵלֶּה מוֹעֲדֵי ה' מִקְרָאֵי קֹדֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר תִּקְרְאוּ אֹתָם בְּמוֹעֲדָם: {ה} בַּחֹדֶשׁ הָרִאשׁוֹן בְּאַרְבָּעָה  עָשָׂר לַחֹדֶשׁ בֵּין הָעַרְבָּיִם **פֶּסַח** לַה': {ו} וּבַחֲמִשָּׁה עָשָׂר יוֹם לַחֹדֶשׁ הַזֶּה חַג הַמַּצּוֹת
>    לַה' שִׁבְעַת יָמִים מַצּוֹת תֹּאכֵלוּ: {ז} בַּיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן מִקְרָא קֹדֶשׁ יִהְיֶה לָכֶם כָּל מְלֶאכֶת עֲבֹדָה לֹא תַעֲשׂוּ: {ח} וְהִקְרַבְתֶּם אִשֶּׁה לַה' שִׁבְעַת יָמִים בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִקְרָא קֹדֶשׁ כָּל מְלֶאכֶת עֲבֹדָה לֹא תַעֲשׂוּ:‏ 
>    ט} וַיְדַבֵּר ה' אֶל מֹשֶׁה לֵּאמֹר: {י} דַּבֵּר אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאָמַרְתָּ אֲלֵהֶם כִּי תָבֹאוּ אֶל הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר אֲנִי נֹתֵן לָכֶם וּקְצַרְתֶּם אֶת קְצִירָהּ וַהֲבֵאתֶם אֶת עֹמֶר רֵאשִׁית קְצִירְכֶם אֶל הַכֹּהֵן: {יא} וְהֵנִיף אֶת הָעֹמֶר לִפְנֵי ה' לִרְצֹנְכֶם **מִמָּחֳרַת הַשַּׁבָּת** יְנִיפֶנּוּ הַכֹּהֵן: {יב} וַעֲשִׂיתֶם בְּיוֹם הֲנִיפְכֶם אֶת הָעֹמֶר כֶּבֶשׂ תָּמִים בֶּן שְׁנָתוֹ לְעֹלָה לַה': {יג} וּמִנְחָתוֹ שְׁנֵי עֶשְׂרֹנִים סֹלֶת בְּלוּלָה בַשֶּׁמֶן אִשֶּׁה לַה' רֵיחַ נִיחֹחַ וְנִסְכֹּה יַיִן רְבִיעִת הַהִין: {יד} וְלֶחֶם וְקָלִי וְכַרְמֶל לֹא תֹאכְלוּ עַד עֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה עַד הֲבִיאֲכֶם אֶת קָרְבַּן אֱ-לֹקיכֶם חֻקַּת עוֹלָם לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם בְּכֹל משְׁבֹתֵיכֶם:  {טו} וּסְפַרְתֶּם לָכֶם **מִמָּחֳרַת הַשַּׁבָּת** מִיּוֹם הֲבִיאֲכֶם אֶת עֹמֶר הַתְּנוּפָה שֶׁבַע שַׁבָּתוֹת תְּמִימֹת תִּהְיֶינָה:‏

Comment: Refer to a comment above. Not every year has a Shabbat Hol Hamo'ed Pesach. This year is an example.

Comment: @DanF Although I do understand what you're saying I still don't get why if the Boethusians (or more modern groups) teach that the omer had to be waved on the morrow after the seventh day, this omer had to be brought on the 16th of Nisan according to their view. According to the scriptures one started to count when from 'the time the sickle is first put to the standing corn'; I.e. the time one reaps the harvest and brings an omer of that harvest to the kohanim to wave it before HaShem. How did the Boethusians decided which moment in time this should be, what arguments did they present?

Answer (score 0):

While the Karaites are not the true inheritors of the Boethusian tradition, a famous Karaite has written a good article on the subject. I will paste it here and provide a source:

> The Pharisees argued that Shavuot is to be counted from the first day
>   of the Feast of Unleavened Bread, which they designated a “Sabbath.”
>   According to the Pharisees, “morrow of the Sabbath” means the “morrow
>   of the 1st day of Unleavened Bread.” The ancient Pharisees and their
>   modern day successor the Orthodox rabbis begin the 50-day count to
>   Shavuot on the second day of Unleavened Bread, which is always the
>   16th day of the First Hebrew Month. As a result, the Pharisee Shavuot
>   always fell out in ancient times from the 5th to the 7th day of the
>   Third Hebrew Month (Sivan). After the destruction of the Temple, the
>   Pharisees became the predominant surviving faction among the Jewish
>   leadership and their interpretation is followed by most Jews until
>   this very day. In 359 CE, the Pharisee leader Hillel II established a
>   pre-calculated calendar and ever since the Pharisee Shavuot has always
>   been observed on the 6th of Sivan.
>
> The Essenes who wrote the Dead Sea Scrolls began the 50-day count to
>   Shavuot on a different Sabbath from the Pharisees. In their reckoning,
>   the Omer offering was to be brought on the morrow of the weekly
>   Sabbath, in modern terms: “Sunday.” The Essenes began their count on
>   the Sunday after the seven-days of the Feast of Unleavened Bread. As a
>   result, they always began their count on the 26th day of the First
>   Hebrew Month. The Essenes had a 364-day solar calendar, which began
>   every year on a Wednesday and had fixed lengths for each month. Based
>   on the Essene calendar, Shavuot always fell out on the 15th day of the
>   Third Hebrew Month. The Essenes are presumed to have been wiped out
>   when the Romans invaded Judea in 66-74 CE and only their documents
>   survive today.
>
> The third faction, the Sadducees, agreed with the Essenes that Shavuot
>   must be counted from a weekly Sabbath, but disagreed as to which one.
>   The Sadducees believed the 50-day count must begin on the weekly
>   Sabbath that falls out during the seven-days of the Feast of
>   Unleavened Bread. According to their reckoning, the counting towards
>   Shavuot could begin anywhere from the 15th to the 21st day of the
>   month, depending on what day of the week the Feast of Unleavened Bread
>   began. If Unleavened Bread began on a Sunday, the count would begin on
>   the 15th day of the month. If Unleavened Bread began on a Saturday,
>   the count would begin on the 16th day of the month, and so on. Based
>   on this counting, Shavuot could fall out from the 4th to the 12th of
>   the Third Hebrew Month. Karaite Jews have accepted the Sadducee
>   reckoning as the only one to be consistent with the plain meaning of
>   the biblical text.
>
> The bigger problem with the Pharisee interpretation of “Sabbath” is
>   when it comes to the end of the 50-day count. Leviticus 23:16 says,
>
> ```
> “Until the morrow of the seventh Sabbath shall you count fifty days.”
> ```
>
> The 1st day day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread could theoretically
>   be called “Sabbath,” even though the Hebrew Bible never uses this
>   terminology. However, the 49th day of the Pharisee counting is not a
>   Sabbath, unless it happens to fall out on a weekly Sabbath - the 7th
>   day of the week. Consequently, the Pharisee Shavuot is rarely the
>   “morrow of the Seventh Sabbath” as required by Leviticus 23:16. About
>   once every seven years, the Pharisee Shavuot does happen to fall out
>   on the “morrow of the seventh Sabbath.” For example, in the year 2018
>   the Feast of Unleavened Bread begins in the Pharisee reckoning at
>   sunset on Friday March 30. In that year, the Pharisee counting begins
>   on Sunday April 1, 2018 and ends 50 days later on the “morrow of the
>   seventh Sabbath,” Sunday May 20, 2018. However, this is the exception
>   to the rule. In most years, Shavuot according to the Pharisee
>   reckoning is actually the morrow of seventh Monday, the morrow of
>   seventh Tuesday, etc. The only way for Shavuot to consistently be the
>   “morrow of the seventh Sabbath” is for the counting to begin on the
>   morrow of a weekly Sabbath, in modern terms on a “Sunday.” Of course,
>   Scripture did not call this a “Sunday,” because that term did not
>   exist in ancient Hebrew. The ancient Hebrew term for Sunday morning is
>   “morrow of the Sabbath.”
>
> An important verse that confirms the timing of Shavuot appears in the
>   Book of Joshua:
>
> ```
> “And they ate of the produce of the land on the morrow of the Passover, unleavened and parched grain on this very day. And the Manna
> ```
>
> ceased on the morrow when they ate of the produce of the land...”
>   -Joshua 5:11
>
> This verse describes the events surrounding the cessation of the
>   Manna, shortly after the Children of Israel entered the Land of
>   Canaan. To understand this the significance of this verse, we must go
>   back to the Book of the Leviticus, where the Israelites were forbidden
>   to eat of the new crops of the Land of Israel until the day of the
>   Omer offering:
>
> ```
> "And bread and parched grain and ripe grain you shall not eat until this very day, until you bring the sacrifice of your God; it
> ```
>
> shall be an eternal statute for your generations in all your
>   habitations." Leviticus 23:14
>
> When Joshua 5:11 describes the eating of “unleavened bread and parched
>   grain... on this very day" it is using almost the precise wording of
>   Leviticus 23:14 “and bread and parched grain... you will not eat until
>   this very day.” The new produce of the land was forbidden until the
>   Omer offering was brought. Joshua 5:11 is saying that when the
>   Israelites entered the Land for the first time, they observed this
>   commandment and waited until the terms of Leviticus 23:14 were
>   fulfilled. In other words, they waited for the Omer offering before
>   eating the grain of Israel. This has been widely recognized by Jewish
>   Bible commentators throughout history, such as the 11th Century rabbi
>   Rashi who explains on Joshua 5:11, “morrow of the Passover is the day
>   of the waving of the omer.”
>
> Joshua 5:11 is saying that the first Omer offering in the Land of
>   Israel was brought on the “morrow of the Passover.” Immediately after
>   this, the Children of Israel were permitted to eat of the new crops of
>   the Land. For the first time, the Israelites pulled out their sickles
>   and ate of the good bounty of their new homeland.
>
> To understand the phrase “morrow of the Passover” we need to define
>   two terms: “morrow” and “Passover.” The Hebrew word for “morrow” is
>   mi-mocharat which refers to “the morning after.” In the phrase “morrow
>   of the Sabbath” it describes Sunday morning, the morning after the
>   24-hour Sabbath.
>
> Today we commonly refer to the Feast of Unleavened Bread as
>   “Passover.” However, in the Hebrew Bible, the term “Passover” (Pesach)
>   always refers to the Pascal sacrifice. The “morrow of the Passover” is
>   the morning after the Passover sacrifice. The sacrifice was
>   slaughtered at twilight at the end of the 14th day of the First Hebrew
>   Month (Nissan) and eaten on the evening that began the 15th day of the
>   First Hebrew Month (see Exodus 12:18; Deuteronomy 16:4). The morrow of
>   the Passover is therefore the morning of the 15th day of the First
>   Hebrew Month.
>
> Confirmation of the meaning of the phrase “morrow of the Passover” can
>   be found in a verse in the Book of Numbers:
>
> ```
> “And they traveled from Ramesses in the first month on the fifteenth of the month; on the morrow of the Passover the Children of
> ```
>
> Israel went out with a high hand in the eyes of all Egypt.” - Numbers
>   33:3
>
> This verse describes the day of the Exodus from Egypt as both the 15th
>   of the First Hebrew Month and as the “morrow of the Passover.”
>
> What all this means is that the first Omer offering in Israel took
>   place on the 15th day of the First Hebrew Month. The first year that
>   the Israelites entered Canaan, the 14th of the First Hebrew Month must
>   have fallen out on a Sabbath so that the 15th of that month was a
>   Sunday. In that year, the “morrow of the Passover” happened to also be
>   the “morrow of the Sabbath,” what we call “Sunday morning.” This
>   proves the Pharisee interpretation of Leviticus 23:15 to be wrong.
>   According to the Pharisees, the Omer offering could only be brought on
>   the morning of the 16th of the First Hebrew Month, but in the year
>   that the Israelites entered Canaan, they brought the sacrifice one day
>   earlier.
>
> The great 12th Century rabbinical Bible commentator Ibn Ezra mentions
>   a “Roman sage” who brought Joshua 5:11 as proof for the Pharisee
>   interpretation. According to this Roman rabbi, Joshua 5:11 is no less
>   than the silver bullet, the irrefutable proof for the Pharisee
>   position. This Roman rabbi argued that since Passover begins on the
>   15th of the First Hebrew Month (Nissan), the “morrow of the Passover”
>   must be the 16th. This is exactly when the Pharisees believe the Omer
>   offering is supposed to be brought, on the 16th of the First Hebrew
>   Month. If the Israelites brought the Omer on the 16th day of the First
>   Hebrew Month in the year they entered the Land of Israel, argues the
>   Roman rabbi, it proves that the Pharisees are correct in beginning the
>   50-day count to Shavuot on the 16th.
>
> According to Ibn Ezra, bringing up Joshua 5:11 was a disaster for the
>   Pharisee position:
>
> ```
> “[The Roman Rabbi] did not know that it cost him his life, for the Passover is on the fourteenth and its morrow is the fifteenth, and so
> ```
>
> it is written, “And they traveled from Ramesses in the first month,
>   etc.” (Numbers 33:3). Eating parched grain is forbidden until the
>   waving of the Omer.”
>
> Desperate to salvage the situation, Ibn Ezra proposes a novel
>   re-interpretation of Joshua 5:11. Previous rabbis understood this
>   verse to describe the Israelites eating the new grain of the Land of
>   Israel, which only becomes permissible each year after the Omer
>   offering is brought (Leviticus 23:14). The time between harvest and
>   the Omer offering might be anywhere for a few hours to a couple of
>   weeks. During this interim period, the new grain must be stored and
>   only old grain may be eaten, that is, grain from a previous year’s
>   harvest. Since the Israelites were new in the Land of Israel, they did
>   not have any grain from previous years. They had been wandering in the
>   desert eating Manna for 40 years. As soon as they entered the Land,
>   they harvested the grain they found growing in the fields of Jericho.
>   They then waved the Omer, the first sheaf of the harvest, making all
>   their new harvest permissible to eat and began the 50-day count to
>   Shavuot.
>
> From Ibn Ezra’s perspective, the Israelites did this one day too
>   early, on the morning of the 15th day of the First Hebrew Month.
>   According to the Pharisees, the Omer must always be brought on the
>   16th day of the First Hebrew Month. Ibn Ezra’s ingenious solution to
>   this embarrassing biblical fact of history is to add the word “old” to
>   Joshua 5:11. If the Israelites ate “old grain,” that is, grain
>   harvested in a previous year, then the verse has nothing to do with
>   the Omer offering or the 50-day count to Shavuot.
>
> Ibn Ezra’s new interpretation was highly influential, more than most
>   people realize. When Christian scholars started translating the Bible
>   into English, they went to Jewish rabbis to learn the Hebrew language.
>   When it came to Joshua 5:11, the rabbis told the Christian translators
>   to add the word “old” to the verse. More precisely, they told them
>   that the word “grain,” in Hebrew avur, actually means “old grain.” As
>   a result, Ibn Ezra’s novel interpretation is reflected in the most
>   famous English translation of all time, the King James Version:
>
> ```
> And they did eat of the old corn of the land on the morrow after the passover, unleavened cakes, and parched corn in the selfsame day.
> ```
>
> Joshua 5:11 –King James Version
>
> Most translations do not employ the Ibn Ezra translation trick of
>   adding the word “old.” This is true for both Christian and Jewish
>   translations. Here are a few examples:
>
> ```
> “On the day after the passover, on that very day, they ate the produce of the land, unleavened cakes and parched grain.” New Revised
> ```
>
> Standard Version
>
> ```
> The day after the Passover, that very day, they ate some of the produce of the land: unleavened bread and roasted grain.” New
> ```
>
> International Version
>
> ```
> “And they did eat of the produce of the land on the morrow after the passover, unleavened cakes and parched corn, in the selfsame day.”
> ```
>
> Jewish Publication Society 1917
>
> ```
> “On the day after the passover offering, on that very day, they ate of the produce of the country, unleavened bread and parched
> ```
>
> grain.” Jewish Publication Society 1985
>
> ```
> “And they ate of the grain of the land on the morrow of the Passover, unleavened cakes and parched grain on this very day.”
> ```
>
> Judaica Press
>
> These translations were made by people who read Hebrew and they knew
>   that the word “old” was simply not there. The Christian translators of
>   the King James Version, on the other hand, did not know this and took
>   someone else’s word for it.
>
> Ibn Ezra himself must have known that adding “old” to the verse was
>   not the correct linguistic interpretation. In his introduction to his
>   commentary on the Torah, Ibn Ezra declares that the rules of language
>   and grammar must be bent to fit rabbinical interpretation when it
>   affects practical religious observance. Adding the word “old” to
>   Joshua 5:11 is a clear example of bending the rules of the language.
>   Ibn Ezra reveals his true understanding when he points out in response
>   to the Roman rabbi, “Eating parched grain is forbidden until the
>   waving of the Omer.” He only mentions the “parched grain” from Joshua
>   5:11 and not the “unleavened bread” because he knows it disproves the
>   very thing the Pharisees wanted to prove.
>
> “Parched grain,” in Hebrew kali, refers to nearly ripe grain that is
>   still slightly moist. The farmers would harvest this moist grain early
>   and parch it in fire to make it crunchy and delicious. Parched grain
>   could only come from a freshly harvested crop, not from old grain!
>   Joshua 5:11 says the Israelites ate “parched grain” on the morrow of
>   the Passover, on the morning of the 15th day of the First Hebrew
>   Month. The “unleavened bread” could theoretically have come from the
>   old grain, as Ibn Ezra suggested, but the parched grain had to be new
>   grain. Year-old moist grain would go bad, so parched grain could only
>   be “new” grain from that year’s harvest. This new crop would be
>   forbidden to eat until the waving of the Omer, which took place on the
>   “morrow of the Passover,” which Ibn Ezra knew from Numbers 33:3 was
>   the morning of the 15th day of the month. That first year in the Land
>   of Israel, the Israelites ate the new grain and began the 50-day count
>   to Shavuot on the 15th of the First Hebrew Month. This was one day too
>   early for the rabbinical reckoning, which is why Ibn Ezra says that
>   bringing Joshua 5:11 into the discussion of the timing of Shavuot cost
>   the Roman rabbi his life - figuratively speaking, of course.
>
> One technical point to consider is that the word “morrow” is the
>   operative term in the phrase the “morrow of the Sabbath.” Joshua 5:11
>   makes it clear that the “morrow” has to be during the seven days of
>   the Feast of Unleavened Bread. The Sabbath itself might actually
>   precede these seven days, as it did that first year the Israelites
>   entered the Land of Israel.
>
> In ancient times, the Pharisee Shavuot would coincide with the
>   Biblical Shavuot about once every seven years. This would happen
>   whenever the First Hebrew Month began with the sighting of the new
>   moon on a Friday night. In years such as these, the 16th day of the
>   month would be both the second day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread
>   and the morrow of the weekly Shabbat. The modern rabbinical calendar
>   established by Hillel II in 359 CE calculates the beginning of the
>   month using the dark moon, making this a less common scenario.

Source: https://www.nehemiaswall.com/truth-shavuot

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/548/759 https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/75/759

Comment: @DoubleAA i will work on implementing those guidelines later tonight

Comment: Aaron; These kind of article's almost always focus on why it had to be the day after the seventh day or why it had to be the second day of the Pesach on which one should start counting. The Pharisees link with Pesach is made quite easily, and is most often presented as a point of argument, but the reason why the  Boethusians link their view Pesach by stating that one should count from after the Pesach from the day after the seventh day which is a shabat is unclear to me.